# How to get fractional part in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

is there any way to print out the fractional part of a double,

My double number,

```
4734.602654867
```

I want only `6026` from it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that using `split()`

Like this..

```dart
var s = 4734.602654867;
var a = s.toString().split('.')[1]. substring(0,4); // here a = 6026
```

Hope it solves your issue..

Comment: yes it solves my problem, can you explain or provide resources how this works?? THANKS!!

Comment: Well, initially `number(s)` is converted to `string(a = s.toString)`..then, as the integer and decimal are separated by a `'.'` we can use the `split(.split('.'))` method to get them,in this case..decimal part is([1])..then, we can get the first '4' digits with `substring(0,4)`..hope it makes clear..kindly accept it as answer..if it solves your issue..TQ :)

Comment: You can get more information about `split` [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/String/split.html%23:~:text%3DSplits%2520the%2520string%2520at%2520matches,Hello%2520world!%2522%253B%2520string.&ved=2ahUKEwjz7br97KvqAhXU6XMBHWFrBqsQFjABegQIDhAF&usg=AOvVaw1Mdaagep3AnH7H1u8T4okX) and about `substring` [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/String/substring.html&ved=2ahUKEwi3-5TX5qvqAhVfwTgGHfqCANkQFjAAegQIBBAB&usg=AOvVaw2Ql8B14o5_TGo3SSdx-k6y)

Comment: Thanks, simplest answer!!

Comment: This solution only works for double with at least 4 digits after `.`. If you try with `4734.602` you get a `RangeError`

Comment: Of course, yes. But, my answer particularly for this question..and if it requires to get less/more than 4 digits..then it can be done by changing the parameter for `substring`..right..so, I don't think that's a big deal..

Comment: Terrible answer... `substring(0,4)` is hardcoded... as is the decimal `'.'` (what if you pass it an integer?)... and you should (almost) never do numerical processing in text.

Answer (score 24):

There is a `truncate()` function for double type which returns the integer part discarding the fractional part. We can subtract that from the original double to get the fraction.

```
double myDouble = 4734.602654867;
double fraction = myDouble - myDouble.truncate();
print(fraction);                                   // --> prints 0.602654867
```

*Edit:*
If we want 4 digits specifically from the fractional part, we can do this..

```
int result = (fraction*10000).truncate();  
print(result);                                    // --> prints 6026
```

To do all this one line, we can do it like this..

```
int result = ((myDouble - myDouble.truncate())*10000).truncate(); // <-- 6026
```

Comment: But, I believe, that's not the required part..as the question says..`6026` is required, not the entire fraction part..!

Answer (score 5):

Something like

```dart
import 'dart:math' show pow;
var number = 4734.602654867;
var wantedDigits = 4;
var fraction = (number % 1 * pow(10, wantedDigits)).floor();
print(fraction);
```

should work.

[Dartpad example](https://dartpad.dev/7bf7aa276288a84c2685fc393524e613).

Comment: Dart don't have any direct method to perform this, Right??

Comment: It doesn't. But such method can be implemented in one line: `int getFraction(double number, int digits) => (number % 1 * pow(10, digits)).floor();`

Comment: wrong output,

Try this,

```var number = 3.3;
  var wantedDigits = 1;
  print(getFraction(number, digits));`

Answer (score 1):

```
final double number = 4734.602654867;
final String result = number.toStringAsFixed(5).split('.').last.substring(0,4);
```

Comment: It is giving result as `6027`, `6026` expected

Answer (score 0):

```
void main() {
  double d = 4734.602654867;
  print(((d - d.floor()) * 10000).floor()); // --> prints 6026
}
```

[floor](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/dart_programming/dart_programming_floor_method.htm) method returns the decimal part of the number

Answer (score 0):

I got a simpler and straight forward answer, especially if you want to still use the fractional part as decimal, and not as a string

```dart
  double kunle = 300.0/7.0; // the decimal number

  int s = kunle.floor(); // takes out the integer part

  double fractionalPart = kunle-s; // takes out out the fractional part

  print(fractionalPart); // print the fractional part
```